# Sequential Algebraic Problem:

Tags: sequences-and-series, intuition

[image]

The first part i) I can do.

For part ii) this is how far I can get:

If n is odd then $y=px+qy$

If n is even then $x=py+qx$

After some rearranging i end up with $y(1-q)=px$ & $x(1-q)=py$ and dividing one by the other I can show that $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{x}{y}$ from which it follows that $x^2=y^2$ and so $x=y$ or $x=-y$ as required. But how do I show that $q\pm p=1$?

For part iii) I'm afraid I have simply no idea, so any hints or advice will be greatly appreciated.

With kind regards.

Thank you very much.

Following shooting-squirrel's advice I get:

$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)z$ [1]

$(1-pq)z=(p^2+q)y$ [2]

$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)y$ [3]

Rearranging I get $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{(p^2+q)z}{1-pq}$ & $z=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}$ $\implies$ $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{((p^2+q)^2)y}{(1-pq)^2}$ $\implies$ $p^2 + q=1-pq$ $\ne p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0$ which was what was required.

By the way this might be because you might have made a mistake with those 3 equations the ones i get are:

$z=py+qx$ [For $n=0$]

$x=pz+qy$ [For $n=1$]

$y=px+qz$ [For $n=2$]

leading to

$(1-pq)x=(q^2+p)z$ [1]

$(1-pq)z=(q^2+p)y$ [2]

$(1-pq)x=(q^2+p)y$ [3]

Comment: I get something different from what you are asked to prove...

Comment: I could do part 2 in my head, I have to take a pencil for part 3, but I'm lying on my bed, with my laptop on myself.

Comment: -1 for posting a picture of the text

Comment: @miracle173 Why do that? I did my best to enlarge it but it wouldn't let me make it any bigger (you can still see it after all right?) Seriously though, Whats wrong with the picture of the text?

Comment: @shooting-squirrel Your right i have made a mistake, i will amend it now

Comment: @miracle173 Ok i had to look up on meta how to re-size the picture of the text. Now that it looks a lot better perhaps you could give me my +1 back?

Comment: @user144533 If it's so important, I'll give it to you...

Comment: @user144533 Up, I was notifying you of the fact that the problem statement is wrong. The solver is asked to prove(in part 2) that $p+q=1$ or $p-q$=1, and that is not true, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: I don't like the upload of pictures instead of text. Pictures are not searchable, text of pictures cannot be copied and pasted, the size of the font cannot be changed. Pictures can be removed from the server. Your picture does not bring any additional infomation So why do you not post text?   http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions

Comment: @miracle I guess it was just quicker and easier than typing the whole question out. None the less i do see your point now that you mention it, as with pictures there is no way to extraxt information from them in subsequent answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 2**

$y=px+qy$

$x=py+qx$

$(1-q)y=px$

$(1-q)x=py$

If $q=1 => p=0$

Otherwise,

$y=\frac{p}{1-q}x=(\frac{p}{1-q})^2y$

$\frac{p}{1-q}=1$ or $\frac{p}{1-q}=-1 => x=y$ or $x=-y$

$\frac{p}{1-q}-1=0 => p+q=1$

$\frac{p}{1-q}+1=0 => p-q=-1$

**Part 3**

Our sequence, $t_{n}$ looks like x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z,...

Using the first rule in your problem statement(which applies to any 3 consecutive numbers in the sequence)

$x=py+qz$(#)   (here $t_{n+2}=x$)

$y=pz+qx$(##)  (here $t_{n+2}=y$)

$z=px+qy$(###) (here $t_{n+2}=z$)

All you need to do here, is to apply the same idea as in part 2. Use (##) to substitute for y in (#), then you'll get a relation between x and z. Now, you want to get a relation between z and y, and afterwards, between y and x. Now, use the the 3 newly acquired relations as we used them in part 2.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer i just need to know how you came up with these 3 equations: $x=py+qz$,
$y=pz+qx$, $z=px+qy$ as last time I used the fact that n was odd or even but i'm not sure what rule you used to get these?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Following your advice I get:

$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)z$ [1]


$(1-pq)z=(p^2+q)y$ [2]


$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)y$ [3]

Rearranging I get $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{(p^2+q)z}{1-pq}$ & $z=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}$ $\implies$ $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{((p^2+q)^2)y}{(1-pq)^2}$ $\implies$ $p^2 + q=1-pq$ $\ne p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0$ which was what was required. Can you please show me how to get to $p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0$? then I can finally tick your answer which is what i've been wanting to do. You havebeen great in helping me solve the part ii) so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry comment was too long so had to move here instead, Following your advice I get:

$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)z$ [1]

$(1-pq)z=(p^2+q)y$ [2]

$(1-pq)x=(p^2+q)y$ [3]

Rearranging I get $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{(p^2+q)z}{1-pq}$ 
& $z=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}$ $\implies$ $x=\frac{(p^2+q)y}{1-pq}=\frac{((p^2+q)^2)y}{(1-pq)^2}$

$\implies$ $p^2 + q=1-pq$ $\ne p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0$ which was what was required. Can you please show me how to get to $p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0$? then I can finally tick your answer which is what i've been wanting to do.

By the way this might not be working out because you might have made a mistake with those 3 equations, these are the ones i get:

$z=py+qx$ [For $n=0$]

$x=pz+qy$ [For $n=1$]

$y=px+qz$ [For $n=2$]

leading to

$(1-pq)x=(q^2+p)z$ [1]

$(1-pq)z=(q^2+p)y$ [2]

$(1-pq)x=(q^2+p)y$ [3]

Comment: $p^2 + q=1-pq => p^2-1=-q-pq => (p-1)(p+1)=-q(p+1)$ . If $p$ is different from $-1$, then $p-1=-q <=> p+q=1$. Given this, $ p^3 +q^3 +3pq-1=0  <=> p^3 +q^3 +3pq(p+q)=1 <=> (p+q)^3=1$.